# Add mypy options --enable-incomplete-feature=Unpack in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, mypy, pyproject.toml

I would like to use the experimental `typing.Unpack` in my project.

In the CLI command, it works when adding `--enable-incomplete-feature=Unpack`.

However, I have mypy issues reported by pyright (in neovim), therefore I would like to add this option in the section `mypy` of `pyproject.toml`.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *should* be like this

```
[tool.mypy]
enable_incomplete_feature = ["Unpack"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was sure I already tested it, but actually nope, it works!